# unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede

Tags: java, openjdk, certificates, elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch-certutil to generate a certificate

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert -out /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elastic-certificates.p12 -pass ""
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Encrypt Private Key failed: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302528/java-security-keystoreexception-when-running-my-app-with-docker-compose) which recommend downgrading Java version, but I don't know how to do this?

The other [suggestion](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/941) is to edit: **sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore** and add the following:

```
keystore.pkcs12.keyProtectionAlgorithm=PBEWithSHA512AndAES_256
```

But again I am not sure how to do this?

This is how I installed Java on my Ubuntu server:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

and this is my Java version: **/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64**